# SSH ForwardAgent access to github isn't working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-agent

I am working in a team with two other guys. We all have access to a server with our personal SSH keys and we can directly login to the server. We are using ForwardAgent, more specifically all three of us have something like this in our `~/.ssh/config` (the only difference is that I have `id_rsa_osx` and they have `id_rsa`):

```
Host api1.domain.com
  User deployer
  Port 10000
  ForwardAgent yes
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_osx
```

So by typing `ssh api1.domain.com` we all have access to the server as the user deployer. The thing is that I am the only one who doesn't have access to the github directly from the server. So, when I am typing `ssh -T git@github.com` I am getting `Permission denied (publickey).` For the other guys it works correctly.

I have access from my local machine to github with this key and my config for github is this:

```
Host github.com
  User git
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_osx
```

I also tried this command `echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK"` and returned `/tmp/ssh-yz4zn4fqMf/agent.16068`. I have the key on the github and I also tried to add another key with the same results. I am completely out of ideas, what else should I try?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I haven't added my key to ssh-agent. I typed `ssh-add my_key_path`and it worked (To check if you have added it, type `ssh-add -l`).